# cURL requesting URL with whitespaces in URL.. What to do

Tags: php, parsing, curl, communication

So I'm trying to curl this URL:

[http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/Screen shot 2011-04-28 at 8.13.21 PM.png](http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/Screen%20shot%202011-04-28%20at%208.13.21%20PM.png)

URL Encoded it reads as:

`http%3A%2F%2Fimages.fastcompany.com%2Fupload%2FScreen+shot+2011-04-28+at+8.13.21+PM.png`

However, curl needs it to be decoded into a proper URL obviously.

How do i get around this problem? cURL drops off the rest of the string as soon as it reaches any whitespace... :(

I should mention I can't wrap the URL with double quotes as it is a variable being posted.

Edit: hahahahaha wowwwwww brainfart.. thanks guys :P

Comment: this is another alternative to doing exactly that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just use str_replace.

```
echo str_replace ( ' ', '%20', 'http://images.fastcompany.com/upload/Screen shot 2011-04-28 at 8.13.21 PM.png' );
```

Answer (score 28):

Perhaps try replacing spaces with `%20`?

Answer (score 10):

I use:

```
$link = trim($link);
$link = str_replace ( ' ', '%20', $link);
```

Answer (score 3):

For me just to put the name with spaces between **""** worked.

Example

```
curl --upload-file "001- name - lastName.pdf" https://transfer.sh/ernesto
```

Notice the use of "" in "001- name - lastName.pdf"

Answer (score 2):

Use the `str_replace();` function. Replace your `" "` with `"%20"`

Answer (score 0):

**On Windows**, you can use notepad++

1. Write the text in the file and open it in notepad++.
2. Select an empty string in the text and then click on search.
3. Search box will appear, Now click on replace tab.
4. Select the Extended check box in the Search Mode option.
5. Click replace
   [image]