# Checking if Image exist using url returns false in some ocasions

Tags: php, image, url, curl

I'm wondering what would make this code falsely fail. It returns false result when passing certain Image URLs. I don't have control of what the URL is, but I can encode it somehow to make this work?

I assume the problem lays with the space located in the Image URL. How to avoid this?

```
function checkRemoteFile($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    return (curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE);
}
```

Comment: if you get false back, then something failed, and you should be checking `curl_error($ch)` to find out why.

Comment: Thanks Marc B. I need to do more reading on cURL, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$url = str_replace(' ','%20',$url);` to urlencode the spaces.

Comment: I just found it right before I seen your answer. But thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931853/curl-requesting-url-with-whitespaces-in-url-what-to-do