# Trouble updating MongoDB using Python/PyMongo with REST api

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, rest, pymongo

Hello I am having trouble updating a MongoDB document while using a Python REST API.
Here is the Python code:

```
import json
import bottle
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bottle import route, run, request, abort

connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['city']
collection = db['inspections']

#Create 
@route('/create', method='POST')
def post_create():

    data=json.load(request.body)
    id=data["id"]
    certificate_number=data["certificate_number"]   
    business_name=data["business_name"]
    date=data["date"]
    result=data["result"]
    sector=data["sector"]
    result=collection.insert_one({'id': id, 'certificate_number': certificate_number, 'business_name' : business_name, 'date' : date, 'result' : result, 'sector' : sector}).inserted_id
    return json.loads(json.dumps(result, indent=4, default=json_util.default))

#Update
@route('/update', method='GET')
def update():

    id=request.query.id
    result=request.query.result
    myquery = {"id": "10011-2017-TEST" }
    newvalues = { "$set": { "result" : result } }
    collection.update(myquery, newvalues)
```

After I start the above Python code, these are the two queries I am running in my terminal:

```
#Create
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id" : "10011-2017-TEST","certificate_number" : 9278833,"business_name" : "ACME TEST INC.","date" : "Feb 20 2017","result" : "No Violation Issued","sector" : "Test Retail Dealer - 101"}' http://localhost:8080/create

#Update
curl http://localhost:8080/update?id="10011-2017-TEST"&result="Violation Issued"
```

The first curl command works perfectly.
However, when I run the second curl update command, I receive an empty "result".

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e48b39618882a084aa35b86"),
        "sector" : "Test Retail Dealer - 101",
        "certificate_number" : 9278833,
        "result" : "",
        "date" : "Feb 20 2017",
        "business_name" : "ACME TEST INC.",
        "id" : "10011-2017-TEST"
}
```

I need the "result" to change from "No Violation Issued" to "Violation Issued". I think I am close, because I know the second update curl command is referencing the correct document, however, it is not updating the "result" properly. I am suspecting the python function can not see the second part of the query, resulting in a blank update.

Comment: Perhaps the second curl command is not working because of whitespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931853/curl-requesting-url-with-whitespaces-in-url-what-to-do

Answer (score 1):

axme100 is correct, the whitespace is your problem. There's few ways to work around it different shell quotes /escapes etc. but the easiest is probably:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/update?id=10011-2017-TEST&result=Violation%20Issued'
```

Put the whole thing in single quotes whenever you have an `&` in the query string to prevent the shell running it in the background.